# IE6 attempts to install missing office component when using excanvas to draw image

Tags: javascript

I have a page that uses excanvas to draw some images. While testing the new page in IE6, one computer attempts to open office 2000 and install a missing component. If the office 2000 install is canceled the vml images appear. This problem only happens on one of my test machines but it still worries me.

Anyone seen this issue when using IE6 and excanvas before?

Comment: You may want to look into flashcanvas, which has better performance.

Comment: I'm getting a similar problem with jquery q-tip and IE8 kicking off the office 2000 installer. Weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turns out VML had been associated with a virus and as a quick fix some people removed or renamed vgx.dll. This causes very odd behavior when VML tries to run and triggered an Office application. I assume this is because windows couldn't find the dll and tried to install or run the program that was associated. Office uses VML so it makes a little sense. Anyway, we called Microsoft and they said it was probably only going to happen on 1% of machines. This was 2 years ago so probably much less now. Anyone who has upgraded away from XP and IE6 probably doesn't have this issue anymore since that dll would have been replaced with a good version.

Answer (score 2):

First of all: With my OSX/Linux background I'm not an IE6 expert at all! :)

That said: It looks like a [MIME-Type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME_type) problem to me. Is there a way to associate MIME-Types to applications in IE6? If yes, compare the settings of the two IE6 setups and look for differences.

Comment: I turns out Google maps has the same issue. We called Microsoft and they say this will happen on a very small percentage of IE6 users. Uninstalling office 2000 made the issue go away on the test box.